# Getting an error while trying to create a SuperUser for Netbox thru Ubuntu, Whats my solve?

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-20.04, netbox

I'm trying to get an instance of Netbox setup. I'm at the step where I need to create a super user.
As per documentation, I'm running `source /opt/netbox/venv/bin/activate`
and confirm i'm in the venv
Followed by `python3 manage.py createsuperuser`

What I get in response is

`You have 167 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, circuits, contenttypes, dcim, django_rq, extras, ipam, sessions, social_django, taggit, tenancy, users, virtualization, wireless.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/netbox/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "auth_user" does not exist
LINE 1: ...user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user...
^

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/netbox/netbox/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/opt/netbox/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/opt/netbox/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 440, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/opt/netbox/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 402, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "/opt/netbox/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 88, in execute
return super().execute(*args, **options)
File "/opt/netbox/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 448, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/opt/netbox/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 109, in handle
default_username = get_default_username(database=database)
File "/opt/netbox/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/**init**.py", line 163, in get_default_username
auth_app.User._default_manager.db_manager(database).get(
File "/opt/netbox/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/netbox/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 646, in get
num = len(clone)
File "/opt/netbox/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 376, in **len**
self._fetch_all()
File "/opt/netbox/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1867, in _fetch_all
self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
File "/opt/netbox/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 87, in **iter**
results = compiler.execute_sql(
File "/opt/netbox/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1398, in execute_sql
cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/opt/netbox/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
return self._execute_with_wrappers(
File "/opt/netbox/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 80, in _execute_with_wrappers
return executor(sql, params, many, context)
File "/opt/netbox/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
File "/opt/netbox/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in **exit**
raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
File "/opt/netbox/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "auth_user" does not exist
LINE 1: ...user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user...`

Originally I was getting an error with my authorized users where I had forgot to put it in quotes. Fixed that, and this was the next error to come out.

I found the line in question, but I'm just not sure how I should change it to pass this command successfully?

Answer (score 0):

See this part of your output:

```
You have 167 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, circuits, contenttypes, dcim, django_rq, extras, ipam, sessions, social_django, taggit, tenancy, users, virtualization, wireless. Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
```

Try applying your django migrations as prompted:

`python manage.py migrate`

This will install the necessary database tables where your new superuser will be stored.